# How to center a Div from anywhere to the center of page with pure css?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have 4 divs with fixed width and height. They are position in line with margins at the center of page.

When the user clicks on any of the boxes the rest of the box hides except the selected box. However, at this point, I want the selected box to be centered in page with slow animation.

I can't seem to center the box with animation (moving slowly from its initial position to the center of the page.

[image]

This is what I have so far for css:

```css
.login-container ul li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 52px;
  padding: 54px 34px;
  width: 27.2%;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.82);
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #98a8b5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transition: all 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  -o-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
}
li.selected {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  display: block !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s;
  transition: all 2s;
  position: absolute !important;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Please if you can, don't provide a jquery solution.

Since its mostly done in angularjs, I dont think the html would help too much,but here it is the html in angularjs:

```js
< div class = "login-container" >
  < ul >
  < li * ngFor = "let login of Logins; let i = index" [hidden] = "!login.show" [class.selected] = "ifOneElement && login.show" > {
    {
      login.name
    }
  } < div class = "{{login.className}}" >
  < label > < input(keyup) = "onKey($event)"
placeholder = "{{login.placeholder.username}}" (click) = "hideEverything(); login.show = true; ifOneElement = true " > < /label>
        <label><input (keyup)="onKey($event)" placeholder="{{login.placeholder.password}}"></label >
  < /div>
    </li >
  < /ul>
</div >
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code too?

Comment: Have you looked at absolute positioning and the `transition` property?

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn't do anything @Hum4n01d

Comment: the html is in angularjs, so i think it wouldnt help too much: but ive added anyway. @ovokuro

Comment: You should clarify that you are using Angular 2, especially because AngularJS internally uses a lite version of `jQuery`. Your request of doing this without `JavaScript`, when using a `JavaScript` framework is, frankly, offensive. It's like asking someone to help you with some heavy bags and than tie their legs and blindfold them. Asking for either `vanilla js` or `typescript` - great and understandable. No `js`? Best of luck, m8! Why don't you call me tomorrow?

Comment: You're right, apologies. Would there be a good way of implementing this using typescript? As im fairly new to angular and typescript. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this. In short, I'd make a directive that would calculate required animation from current `getBoudingClientRect()` of `$element` to desired position (fixed in the center of the screen), at which point i'd crossfade the modal/lightbox in. I'm regarded as pretty good at this but I'm not sure I could do it in less than 30 minutes (don't forget it should work cross-browser/cross-device). I'd estimate 40 - 60 minutes. A top 1% Angular2 dev might be able to do this in 15 minutes. It's still a lot for a SO question, though.